# How to inject an AJAX response into an HTML page?

Tags: php, ajax, function

I am trying to call a function when an AJAX request is made. This is my code so far:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.NextPage').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'test.php',
                    data: {x: 1},
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                  success: function(response) {
                      // do not want any alerts or notifications here
                   }

                });

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <button type="button" class="NextPage">go to nextpage</button> 

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['x'])) {
        if ($_POST['x'] == 1) {
            function1();
            }
    }

    function function1() {
       // this is a sample of what im trying to do in this function
        global $resultNUM;
        global $recordsPerPage;
        global $var;
        global $i;
        global $searchid;
        if ($resultNUM >  $recordsPerPage * i) {
            $nexturl = "something";
            $firstloop=false;
            getdata($nexturl, $var,$firstloop);
            $i++;
        } else {
            echo "end of results";
        }
    }

    ?>
</body>
```

I just need `function1` be executed (in which getdata function is called), and for a response to be injected below the button.

Comment: if you want a simple page, you can try use `document.write(response);`, it will show a simple echo

Comment: @kevinabelita echo was just an example.plz check my question again,i have edited function1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from the comment thread on the other answer, most of your code is working. Your AJAX request is made on the client side, it is received by the server, and the response comes back to the browser. You just therefore need a way to inject the text or HTML response back into the page.

You cannot write to the page in the standard way, since it has already been rendered. However, JavaScript gives you access to the "Document Object Model" (or DOM for short) that allows you to modify the elements on the screen programmatically.

To see this in action, add a new section after your button, thus:

```
<button type="button" class="NextPage">go to nextpage</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Now in your success handler, inject the response back into the page. This jQuery code assumes the result is just text:

```
success: function(response) {
    $('#result').text(response);
}
```

If it contains HTML tags, use `html()` instead of `text()`.

So what is happening here? We have selected an element by `id` using the `#` prefix, and the `$()` construct creates for that a jQuery Element object (as long as it exists - and we know it does). This gives us access to the methods on that class that are documented in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your PHP code:

```
if ($_POST["action"] == "function1")
    function1();
```

And in your AJAX call, do this:

```
data: {action: 'function1'},
success: function(response) {
   // do not want any alerts or notifications here
}
```

But I see that you are already doing it. So in the `function1()`, add a small line, that echoes only `OK`. This way, you can get the ack from the PHP script that the function has been executed successfully.

Comment: thankyou.i tried your suggestion,still dont get anything.

Comment: @user3622910: you need to check your AJAX operation is working. Check it is working in your live AJAX viewer in your browser. (In general, if something doesn't work, it's best to offer as much information as you can, otherwise someone helping you will have nothing to go on).

Comment: @halfer i added alert("working");   in   success: function(response)      and i see the alert.so the AJAX is working.but i get nothing from function1.please guide me in understanding what is going wrong.

Comment: Ah, you are expecting a JSON response, but Praveen has suggested a text response. That might be OK depending on your needs, though. Try `alert(response)` instead, to see if this information gets back to the JavaScript.

Comment: @halfer i tried alert(response) and my information gets back and showed as an alert.the alert contains all of my script and html code with a text echoed from function1 in the bottom.but i dont need the alert rather just a simple echo in php.

Comment: @user3622910: what do you mean by "a simple echo in PHP"? When you receive the AJAX reply, the page is already completely rendered, so you can't `echo` anything in the conventional way. Are you wanting to inject HTML/text into a specific point in the document?

Comment: @halfer i must have misunderstood something here.i want function1 be executed when the button is clicked.the fuction1 may include echo "something" and i want that text to be shown when the button is clicked.that is it.thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3622910: right, so where do you want that text to be shown? Please be more specific.

Comment: @halfer below the button,not in an alert or notification.